# Remove file from different directory

Tags: bash, shell

How do I remove certain files from a different directory than `$PWD` using the bash shell script.

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-delete-remove-file/) for `rm`, it appears that `rm` only works in `$PWD`.

Am I forced to use this method:

```
oDir=$PWD
cd directorytoremovefiles
rm files
cd oDir
```

Comment: have you tried "rm directorytoremovefiles/files"?

Comment: @Jason: `$PWD` is provided *by* Bash.

Comment: learned something new... thanks Dennis :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rm` certainly does work for deleting files in another directory.

Whatever gave you that idea from the man page, I certainly hope it's **not** this:

> rm removes each specified file.  By
>   default, it does not remove
>   directories.

The documentation you refer to, talks only about having **write** & **execute** permission to the directory you are deleting from.

So you only need:

```
rm directorytoremovefiles/files
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by YYC,

```
rm $DIR/files
```

Answer (score 0):

`rm` will take any path, relative or absolute. If there is no slash at the beginning of `directorytoremovefiles` then it is a relative path and you may need to store PWD for later. However, you can do this with `pushd` and `popd` or a `cd -` once you're finished. Or, if you run the `cd` and `rm` commands in parens they will run in a subshell, like this: `( cd directory; rm files)` then your working shell will not change directory.